# Agrarian Skies 3.1.2 - How do I get to The End?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm trying to breed ender bees and can only do so in The End.  There's no recipe in NEI for End Portal Frames, but I read online that you can craft the actual portal using 8 ender eyes in a donut shape in the crafting table.  But I tried it and it didn't work :(  So how do I get to The End?

Comment: I checked NEI, the actual portal block doesn't have a recipe, and neither does the portal frame.

Comment: A reddit post suggests the recipe requires 9 Eyes of Ender rather than 8. http://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/23utvd/agrarian_skies_how_does_one_get_to_the_end_world/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an ender cake (recipe is in NEI) and feed it eyes of ender and right click it when you are a bit hungry.

you will appear on a 5x5 obsidian platform in the end and the dragon will be flying around.